# Assistance with Javascript for each loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, each

I am trying to get my program to generate a 4 number pin to be used for a game.

I originally wanted to do this:

```
function paswdGen() {
    var nums = [0, 0, 0, 0];
    for each (var x in nums) {
        x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    }
} 
document.getElementById("nums").innerHTML = nums;
```

How do I use a "for each" loop in javascript without jQuery?

Comment: [0, 0, 0, 0].forEach(function(item,index){});

Comment: nums.forEach(function(number){   ...  });

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Just to point out your number generator can create nr 10 and will not create 0.

Comment: There's no way it'll generate a 10. The return value of `Math.random()` is strictly less than 1. This will result in a value between 1 and 9.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the language feature Array.prototype.forEach. Check out some great documentation from MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Here's a version of your code:

```
var nums = [0, 0, 0, 0];
nums.forEach(function(nums){
    x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
})
```

Comment: I should also add that this method call is Array-specific. There is separate functionality for object and string iteration.

Comment: I used this but it just returned an undefined if I used something like:

`document.getElementById("nums").innerHTML = nums[0];`

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I think [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) may not be what you need here, may I suggest using [`Array.prototype.map instead`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)? (Note that this would work on most browsers and IE9+)

```
// this function would return a string of 4 digits
function paswdGen() {
    var nums = [0, 0, 0, 0];

    return nums.map(function () {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    }).join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var code = '';

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    code += Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
}

console.log(code); // Outputs 1234 (for example)
```

If your goal is to do it with a forEach:

```
var nums = [0, 0, 0, 0];
var code = '';

nums.forEach(function(){
    code += Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
})

console.log(code); // Outputs 1234 (for example)
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to create the array manually:

```
var length = 4;
var range = 10;

Array.apply(null, {length: length}).map(function() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + 1);
});
```

An alternative way:

```
var length = 4;
var range = 10;
var transform = function(random) { return Math.floor(random * range) + 1 };
Array.apply(null, {length: length}).map(Math.random).map(transform)
```